# length of a session key in EC?

Tags: cryptography, session-management, ecc

In elliptic curve cryptography what should be the length of session key? Is there a specific metric to choose one, or are they randomly generated?

I was studying [one paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5379844) about defence against a Sybil attack. In the initial deployment stage of a vehicular ad-hoc network based on roadside unit support they used 16 bytes, but they gave no explanation why.

Answer (score 1):

ECC is less of an encryption algorithm and more of an algorithm construction kit (some pieces not included).

Not all curves are created equal, and key size (both allowable and recommended) are dependent on the curve chosen. See the literature associated with each given curve for details relating for that specific curve.